# Restrict each other from viewing ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS Report as a parameterized report. One of the parameter that i am using is "VendorName".
When i run the report, i am able to see the list of Vendors (Comp1, Comp2, Comp3, Comp4..........Comp50).
But when i select a Vendor (Comp1), i am seeing all the Vendors data instead the one who has selected his (Comp1).

How do i restrict the users to see only their data when they select their name (Comp1) from the Drop down parameter, and should be abel to see others data?
Is there a way that we can restrict each other viewing their reports.

I am using a sql query in the Dataset (Vendor_Name) like;

SELECT DISTINCT Vendor_Name
FROM            MSP_EpmResource_UserView
WHERE        (Vendor_Name IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [VENDOR_NAME]

Answer (score 0):

I would add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement in the Dataset which is providing data to the Tablix in your report.  This is probably not the Vendor_Name Dataset. E.g.

`WHERE Vendor_Name = @Vendor_Name`